# Should I be regularly shrinking my DB or at least my log file?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, dbcc

My question is, should I be running one or both of the shrink command regularly,

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE

OR

DBCC SHRINKFILE

=============================

## background

Sql Server:  Database is 200 gigs, logs are 150 gigs.

running this command

```
SELECT name ,size/128.0 - 
CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int) / 128.0 
AS AvailableSpaceInMB FROM sys.database_files;`
```

produces this output..

MyDB:           159.812500 MB free

MyDB_Log:   149476.390625  MB free

So it seems there is some free space.

Our backup schedule is as follows:

1. Transaction Logs Once an hour
2. Full Backups twice a week
3. Differential Backups 5 times a week

Comment: the data file is almost completely full, but the log appears almost empty - do you have full logging turned on, or just simple? What's the backup schedule for the log file?

Comment: I believe it may have grown when transaction log backup was inadvertently turned off for a period of time, since it has so much free space I would like to shrink it.  

Will shrinking it produce any performance gains?  

Is it safe to run DBCC ShrinkFile at any time?

Will running DBCC ShrinkFile cause performance issues to users querying DB at same time?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend you read [Paul Randal's article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx) on why you should NOT shrink data files (log files yes, data files no).

I won't quote or try to summarise the article as I really wouldn't do it justice! Just something I think you should at the very least be aware of.

Comment: good article, thnks....  still feel like I want to do a one time shrink of my almost entirely empty transaction log table, agree that since we never bulk delete and are only growing we don't need to shrink the DB files

Comment: Too bad that Randal neither mentions anything about fragmentation on a LUN carved out of a disk pool or of the affect of frag in the bpool. His example is totally trivial to the point of being useless.

Comment: Paul Randalll is wrong. WE gained for example speed by shrinking.

Comment: To add further resources to this, as to why shrinking your data files is harmful, there's a good set of further links here: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: @ooutwire - that's an old article. Check out the buffer pool category on my blog which explains about wasted bpool space. And why is that example useless? It's a simple example that people can understand easily.

Comment: @Offler - care to elaborate?

Comment: @PaulRandal We put a lot of data from performance measurements (just different generic performance counters and some of project specific processes from servers/clients) in a MSSQL db. With the first version without shrink the db got quite fast quite huge. As it was huge, it was also slow (selects of data for reports). With shrinking /defrag to ~ 4GB (dump of raw data after a week, for other things the reports had the comp. data) the database was faster in responding. It does matter a lot if someone asks you to get the report quickly and you either need 2 h to create it or 15 min.

Comment: @PaulRandal I did not write that your example was "useless" just "trivial to the point of being useless". It is certainly helpful as a first step at understanding what fragmentation looks like on a single disk; however, only grandma uses a single disk anymore. What the community should be studying is what the hell does SQL Server do when it perceives that logical frag exists. If my bits are on a LUN from a EFD/15k pool or a NAND card or Violin Memory and I am getting 10ms IO, can I reasonably tell people that I don't care about their frag anymore?

Answer (score 4):

The only advantage of shrinking your files is reclaiming the disk space, but here's the caveat - **If your database is just going to grow to fill that space again, shrinking it can actually be detrimental in the long term**. This is because, after a shrink, SQL Server will have to reclaim the disk space as it grows (which takes time, though not much), and it may lead to fragmentation on the physical disk (more of a problem).

If the files grew to be much larger than they normally will be and you want the hard drive space back, then do a shrink. If you're just wondering whether a shrink should be part of your regular maintenance, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

As [rwmnau says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700190/should-i-be-regularly-shrinking-my-db-or-at-least-my-log-file/2700228#2700228), a `SHRINK` isn't normal maintenance - so you shouldn't be doing it regularly. *However*, given that you're backing up the logs every hour and have ~150GB of free space - I'd be tempted to guess that you're never filling that log.

I'd probably `SHRINK` it to a reasonable size, and let it autogrow until you find your balance. You don't want it to autogrow in normal use, but I personally don't like my log files to be 99% empty either.

To guesstimate a reasonable starting point, you can either estimate the maximum number of changes in an hour (your backup log schedule) or just check the used size before a log backup for a few representative cycles.